# What is the difference between common design patterns?

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, factory

I'm new to design patterns and I need a difference between this Singleton, Factory, Command and Facade patterns. They are all "creating" patterns aren't they? Then what is the purpose of each pattern?

Comment: It is a really broad question that could even lead to several different answers on how to use each pattern. There are already a lot of complete Q/A on SO about these patterns too.

Comment: They most certainly do *not* "create" the same thing. Review the basic summaries again, and then if there is confusion ask a question focusing in on narrower specifics. This is far too broad.

Comment: I think you should read more stuff about these pattern (start with Wikipedia), such that you can ask more directed questions, Command and Facade are not even creational patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Singleton  Ensure a class has only one instance, and provide a global point of access to it.
- Command    Encapsulate a request as an object, thereby letting you parameterize clients with different requests, queue or log requests, and support undoable operations.
- Facade Provide a unified interface to a set of interfaces in a subsystem. Facade defines a higher-level interface that makes the subsystem easier to use.
- Factory method Define an interface for creating a single object, but let subclasses decide which class to instantiate. Factory Method lets a class defer instantiation to subclasses.
  You could see more at following links:

[Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern)

[DoFactory](http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns)